# how to install unity3d on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I download unity 3D games editor from [omg ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/08/unity3d-linux-build)
but when i install it, the ubuntu software center give me an eror:

[image]

What should i do?

Comment: It looks like you are trying do install software for 64bit machines on a 32bit computer, is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

Unity Requirements for Linux OS.

- 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 or newer (just like our player, the editor will
  run on most ‘modern’ 64-bit Linux distributions, but official support
  is only provided for 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 or newer)
- Modern Nvidia, AMD, or Intel graphics card with vendor-supported
  graphics drivers

You have `Wrong architecture 'amd64'` error which means that your OS is not **64 bit**. Download and install Ubuntu **64 bit** and that problem should go away.

Comment: Thanks, but i have 2g ram.I can't install 64bit

Comment: Another option is to install windows. There is Unity 32 bit for Linux but there is one for Windows.